# Unreliability of Android ActivityRecognition API

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using Android Play services's Activity Recognition API. This api is not working in a very reliable manner. Sometimes i have to restart the phone to notification broadcasts. I am using the latest Google play services library

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="4323030"
    android:versionName="4.3.23 (1069729-030)" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

</manifest>
```

I am using the sample code provided by on developer.android.com :

> http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

Any thoughts?

PS: Also let me know if you need any other information, I can post it here.

Comment: you might be interested reading my post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177858/activity-recognition-pendingintent-stop-been-called-in-the-middle-of-the-night

Comment: define "Unreliable".  it's not a secret that this API's are not perfect, but if you'll define exactly what's wrong - someone could help

Comment: "Unreliable" means, it suddenly starts misbehaving.. I have setup "detectionIntervalMillis" as 30 secs.. so sometimes it gives proper notification updates but sometimes it give 1 or 2 updates and stops after that without any exception..

Comment: do you have phone with SIGNIFICANT_MOTION_SENSOR?

Comment: tell me what is your phone model/name

Comment: I'm not sure if it have, but if you have, then this member should not return null :     mSignificantMotionSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56999/discussion-between-mudit-and-tal-kanel).